# drop-down box Multiple Price

Tags: price, dropdown-attribute

Is there anyone can suggest the best solution for having multiple pricing on a product page.

I am looking to have a drop-down. this would serve brand new item price (default) and also open-box item price at discounted price....any idea how I can implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in two ways. Configurable products where you use packaging as an attribute or custom options. Be sure let the cheaper one be the default. Especially with custom options, discounts as options do not work well.